# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)[I

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using grails 2.3.7.I got struck in this place.Itried much to find out solution but i din't get which can solve my problem.

```
   2015-10-12 14:15:08,908 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-5]     
   GrailsExceptionResolver.error(213) | NoSuchMethodError occurred when 
   processing request: [GET] /dispatch/renderAsPdf/3621410

   com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)[I. Stacktrace follows:
   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [renderAsPdf] of controller
   [com.mymodelorder.model.DispatchController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
   at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
   at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
   at grails.plugin.multitenant.core.servlet.CurrentTenantServletFilter.doFilter(CurrentTenantServletFilter.java:53)
   at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
   at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
   at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
    ... 9 more
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 9 more
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)[I
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.setMetricDefaults(ITextFontResolver.java:679)
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:610)
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.addCourier(ITextFontResolver.java:410)
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createInitialFontMap(ITextFontResolver.java:390)
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:52)
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:115)
   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:102)
  at grails.plugin.rendering.pdf.PdfRenderingService.doRender(PdfRenderingService.groovy:34)
```

Below is   **BuildConfig.groovy**

```
  repositories {
    inherits false // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    mavenRepo "http://mvnrepository.com/"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"
    mavenRepo "https://raw.github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/mvn-repo"
    mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
 }

dependencies {
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:adaptivepaymentssdk:2.5.106'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7'
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3'
 }


plugins {
    build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
    compile ":scaffolding:2.0.2"
    compile ':cache:1.1.1'
    runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.9" // or ":hibernate4:4.3.4"
    runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
    runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime ":resources:1.2.8"

    compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
    compile ":multi-tenant-single-db:0.8.3"
    compile ":famfamfam:1.0.1"
    compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC2"
    compile ":joda-time:1.5"

    runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
    runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
    compile ":cache-headers:1.1.5"
    compile ":simple-captcha:1.0.0"
    compile ":cache:1.1.7"
    compile ":webxml:1.4.1"
    compile ":easygrid:1.4.5"
    compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"
    compile ":calendar:1.2.1"
    compile ":file-uploader:1.2.1"
    compile ":csv:0.3.1"
    compile ":paypal:0.6.8"
    compile ":rendering:1.0.0"
    /*runtime( "org.grails.plugins:rendering:1.0.0") {
      excludes "itext"
    }*/
    compile ":aws:1.7.5.0"
    compile ":remote-pagination:0.4.8"
    compile ":drop-box:1.3.1"

    compile ':spring-security-oauth:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile ":spring-security-oauth-google:0.3.1"
    compile ':spring-security-oauth-facebook:0.1'
    compile ':spring-security-oauth-linkedin:0.1'
    compile ':spring-security-oauth-twitter:0.1'
 }
```

As i used **dependency-report** command the i found below details related to itext version.

```
+--- org.grails:grails-docs:2.3.7
|    \--- org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8
|    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-gdoc-engine:1.0.1
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.0.8
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6

+--- org.grails.plugins:rendering:1.0.0
|    \--- org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.1.0
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:136
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:136
```

I am not getting why this error is coming earlier it was working fine but
now giving error like itext version kind of as mentioned above.

Please help me out.

Comment: Mb you are sending object with invalid class now, check object class.

Comment: Can you add the code for `com.mymodelorder.model.DispatchController`? Specifically the `.renderAsPdf()` method.

Comment: I have had this before but can't remember the details. I think you are on the right track with conflicting iText versions. Maybe any other of the plugins use iText as well or you have an old iText laying around in you lib/-folder.

Comment: Can anyone help me as i mentioned above dependency report.

Comment: Oh finally i got the solution is in lib folder itext 2.1.5 and 2.1.0 both versions jars are there and checked manually in difference is measured like   public int[] More ...getCharBBox(int c) ; in 2.1.5 and public int[] More ...getCharBBox(char c) ; in 2.1.0 . :)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the problem by excluding the `itext` dependency from one of the plugins. In my case, the conflicting plugins were `export` and `rendering`.

I decided to exclude it from the `export` plugin like this:

`compile (':export:1.6') { excludes 'itext', 'itext-rtf' }`

Comment: this was my case on grails 3.2

Answer (score 2):

Grails 3. These runtime overrides seemed to fix the issue for me:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8'
    runtime 'com.lowagie:itext:2.1.0'
}
```

Here's the post where I found the solution:
https://github.com/gpc/rendering/issues/4

Comment: Next evolution of gradle is to look like yarn =D. Thanks, works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Replaced old dependencies by the following, and it worked:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

The solution was described in this link: **https://github.com/longyu065/flying-saucer/issues/126**